# No Logging With Socket Requests

Tags: java, sockets

So I have this function:

```
 public HashMap<String, Object> ping(String ip, int port) {
    try {
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        sock.setSoTimeout(1000);
        sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), 1000);

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

        out.write(0xFE);

        int b;
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
            if (b != 0 && b > 16 && b != 255 && b != 23 && b != 24) {
                str.append((char) b);
                System.out.println(b + ":" + ((char) b));
            }
        }

        String[] data = str.toString().split("§");
        String serverMotd = data[0];
        int onlinePlayers = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
        int maxPlayers = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("motd", serverMotd);
        map.put("online", onlinePlayers);
        map.put("max", maxPlayers);

        return map;

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works but fills up the log with the following and a lot of it. How could I get rid of this?

```
[13:26:41 INFO]: 32:
[13:26:44 INFO]: 115:s
[13:26:44 INFO]: 32:
[13:26:44 INFO]: 38:&
[13:26:44 INFO]: 114:r
[13:26:44 INFO]: 105:i
```

Ignore this: I'm pretty sure there's a simple solution so I'm just going to fill up space because it looks like my answer is mostly code but I have noting more to say.

UPDATE: Each of the chars after the number is part of the response. For example, if it was a string "lol", three of these messages would be logged, one for each letter.

Comment: I don't see a logger there, where is it declared?\

Comment: Why do you have empty catch ?!

Comment: You should find out who logs it. Which library do you use? Log4j, slf4j...  You should configure it so it prints the category as well and then you will know who is responsible. Then you can either fix it or configure logging to hide these messages.

Comment: @LeosLiterak because if the exception is thrown, the function just returns null since it means that the host is invalid.

Comment: @LeosLiterak I don't use any libraries apart from the Bukkit API (nothing to do wit this) and Java's default 1.7 SDK.

Comment: @hexafraction nowhere do I declare a logger.

Comment: Never ever do this. You can miss other exceptions and programming errors. I would consider hard discussion with team member if I found this. Whole team spent a night finding error in production and it was caused by such empty block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like content of your system.out. Application server redirects standards out and error streams to its log. If you want to get rid of it, then comment that line out.

```
System.out.println(b + ":" + ((char) b));
```